# Change the drop down selected value from an angular controller

Tags: angularjs

I need to change the "selected value" of the drop down from the already saved value in db. How can I do that?

**Controller**

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('ctrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.months = ['January','February','March','April','May','June','July','August','September','October','November','December'];

  $scope.selected='August';//here it's not working ?
});
```

**HTML**

```
<html ng-app="app">
  <body ng-controller="ctrl">
<div class="sample" align="center">
  <h1>AngularJS Combobox</h1>
<select ng-model="selected" ng-options="opt as opt for opt in months" ng-init="selected='March'"></select>
  <h3>You have selected : {{selected}}</h3>
</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

[**My CODE PEN is here.**](http://codepen.io/Sampath-Lokuge/pen/EIwGk)

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the:

```
ng-init="selected='March'"
```

So that your new view code is as follows:

```
<html ng-app="app">
  <body ng-controller="ctrl">
<div class="sample" align="center">
  <h1>AngularJS Combobox</h1>
<select ng-model="selected" ng-options="opt as opt for opt in months"></select>
  <h3>You have selected : {{selected}}</h3>
</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Then how can I give a default load value ?

Comment: You're using two competing methods of default declaration. Just use one - remove the ng-init and use $scope.selected to choose your default, or, instead of removing the ng-init entirely, just change it's value to 'August'.

Comment: Did you run what I showed you? `ng-model="selected"` sets the default load value to what you have set in `$scope.selected='August';`

Comment: @ShawnErquhart No.My requirement is I need to set the default value for the drop down at start up and after the user select one value and it has been saved on the db. When user will come again for the same place where I need to show the saved value from the DB ?

Comment: @JSKNS Yes.When I remove it,it's working.But how can I set it for the first time ? Before user saves it to the DB ?

Comment: What we're showing you is how to set the initial default. Your $scope.selected doesn't show because of a race condition between that expression and the ng-init directive on the element - only use one. To go back to that value after a database save, you'll want to use a promise for the save operation and reset the select field in the promise's return function.

Comment: @Sampath, use the `$scope.selected` value in the controller to try to grab the value from the database. If the value does not exist in the database have it default to `$scope.selected='August';` or `$scope.selected='March';`

Answer (score 1):

To set the initial selected default: set via `$scope.selected` in the controller - don't use `ng-init` for this.

To reset the default after a database save, you'll want to use a promise for the save operation and reset the select field in the promise's return function.